# Is it possible to search by package description in conda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, apt, package-managers

I'm used to search and install packages with apt, under Debian-based distributions, and one useful feature of it is that you can search in the description of packages as well, so you don't need to know the exact name of a package to find it. It can be used in a exploratory way. For example, say I'm searching for packages related to functional programming, but haven't a specific one in mind. I could do just this:

```
(base) user@desktop:~$ apt-cache search functional | grep 'programming'
libio-async-perl - modules for asynchronous event-driven programming
libjs-underscore - JavaScript's functional programming helper library
afnix-doc - Compiler and run-time for the AFNIX programming language (documentation)
elpa-agda2-mode - dependently typed functional programming language — emacs mode
libavutil-dev - FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - development files
libavutil56 - FFmpeg library with functions for simplifying programming - runtime files
libghc-agda-doc - dependently typed functional programming language; documentation
libghc-generic-deriving-dev - generic programming library for generalised deriving
libghc-generic-deriving-doc - generic programming library for generalised deriving; documentation
libghc-reactive-banana-dev - Library for functional reactive programming (FRP)
libghc-reactive-banana-doc - Library for functional reactive programming (FRP); documentation
elixir - functional meta-programming aware language
elpa-ess - Emacs mode for statistical programming and data analysis
faust - functional programming language for realtime audio applications
faust-common - functional programming language for realtime audio applications - common files
fsharp - functional-first programming language - compiler for the CLI
golang-github-go-ldap-ldap-dev - Basic LDAP v3 functionality for the Go programming language
golang-gopkg-ldap.v3-dev - basic LDAP v3 functionality for the GO programming language
hsbrainfuck - interpreter for the brainfuck programming language
libfaust2 - functional programming language for realtime audio applications - libraries
libfsharp-core4.3-cil - functional-first programming language - core runtime library
libfsharp-data-typeproviders4.4-cil - functional-first programming language - data integration library
libghc-generic-deriving-prof - generic programming library for generalised deriving; profiling libraries
libghc-reactive-banana-prof - Library for functional reactive programming (FRP); profiling libraries
libparanoid-perl - module for safer, more secure programming
libreact-ocaml - functional reactive programming in OCaml (plugins)
libreact-ocaml-dev - functional reactive programming in OCaml
lua-moses - Utility library for functional programming in Lua
node-underscore - JavaScript's functional programming helper library - NodeJS
r-cran-lambda.r - GNU R modeling data with functional programming
r-cran-purrr - GNU R functional programming tools
rust-doc - Rust systems programming language - Documentation
rust-src - Rust systems programming language - source code
rustc - Rust systems programming language
urweb - purely functional language for web programming
wadc - programming environment for creating Doom maps
```

Now I installed Anaconda, and noticed the package manager provided, conda, seems to search packages by name only, on running "conda search ". Is there a way to make it behave as apt, searching by description as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to search package descriptions with `conda search`. The query results of `conda search`, including those with the `--info|-i` flag, do not include package description info.

There is limited functionality for retrieving package summaries from Anaconda Cloud. This is provided by the `anaconda show` command in the package `anaconda-client` and only provides exact matching (channel and package). For example,

```bash
(base) $ anaconda show 'conda-forge/r-purrr'
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Name:    r-purrr
Summary: A complete and consistent functional programming toolkit for R.
Access:  public
Package Types:  conda
Versions:
   + 0.2.2
   + 0.2.3
   + 0.2.4
   + 0.2.5
   + 0.3.1
   + 0.3.2
   + 0.3.3
   + 0.3.4

To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge r-purrr
```

However, this does not search the package descriptions like what is done in OP, but only retrieves info on the queried one.